# Interpreting Tensorboard Distributions - Weights not Changing, only Biases

Tags: tensorflow, visualization, distribution, tensorboard

I have a neural network which is organized as follows:

```
conv1 - pool1 - local reponse normalization (lrn2) - conv2 - lrn2 - pool2 -
conv3 - pool3 - conv4 - pool4 - conv5 - pool5 - dense layer (local1) - 
local2 - softmax
```

After looking into the tensorboard's distributions, I got the following:

[image: conv5_biases]
[image: conv5_weights]
[image: local1_biases]
[image: local1_weights]
[image: local2_weights]
[image: softmax_weights]
[image: Loss]
The following figure are the output of the activations over time.

[image: Conv1 Output Distribution]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Therefore, from the loss figure, it is clear that the network is learning. In addition, all of the biases shows as the well that they are modified as a result of learning. But what about the weights, it looks like they haven't changed with time? Is it logical what I am getting from its figures? Please note that I have posted only a subset of the images for the weights and biases in the graph. All weight's figures are similar to what I have presented here, and likewise for the biases **Biases appear to learn, while weights do not!!**

Here is the how I constructed the graph:

```
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
batch_size = 1024
n_classes = 1  # 1 since we need the value of the retrainer.

weights = {
    'weights_conv1': tf.get_variable(name='weights1', shape=[5, 5, 3, 128], dtype=tf.float32,
                        initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(uniform=False, dtype=tf.float32)),
    'weights_conv2': tf.get_variable(name='weights2', shape=[3, 3, 128, 128], dtype=tf.float32,
                        initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(uniform=False, dtype=tf.float32)),
    'weights_conv3': tf.get_variable(name='weights3', shape=[3, 3, 128, 256], dtype=tf.float32,
                        initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(uniform=False, dtype=tf.float32)),
    'weights_conv4': tf.get_variable(name='weights4', shape=[3, 3, 256, 256], dtype=tf.float32,
                        initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(uniform=False, dtype=tf.float32)),
    'weights_conv5': tf.get_variable(name='weights5', shape=[3, 3, 256, 256], dtype=tf.float32,
                        initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(uniform=False, dtype=tf.float32)),
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[128], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='biases1'),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[128], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='biases2'),
    'bc3': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[256], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='biases3'),
    'bc4': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[256], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='biases4'),
    'bc5': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[256], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='biases5')
}

def inference(frames):
    # frames = tf.Print(frames, data=[tf.shape(frames)], message='f size is:')
    tf.summary.image('frame_resized', frames, max_outputs=32)
    frame_normalized_sub = tf.subtract(frames, tf.constant(128, dtype=tf.float32))
    frame_normalized = tf.divide(frame_normalized_sub, tf.constant(255.0), name='image_normalization')

    # conv1
    with tf.name_scope('conv1') as scope:
        conv_2d_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(frame_normalized, weights['weights_conv1'], strides=[1, 4, 4, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv_2d_1_plus_bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_2d_1, biases['bc1'])
        conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv_2d_1_plus_bias, name=scope)

    tf.summary.histogram('con1_output_distribution', conv1)
    tf.summary.histogram('con1_before_relu', conv_2d_1_plus_bias)

    # norm1
    with tf.name_scope('norm1'):
        norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(conv1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75, name='norm1')
    tf.summary.histogram('norm1_output_distribution', norm1)

    # pool1
    with tf.name_scope('pool1') as scope:
        pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(norm1,
                               ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='VALID',
                               name='pool1')
    tf.summary.histogram('pool1_output_distribution', pool1)

    # conv2
    with tf.name_scope('conv2') as scope:
        conv_2d_2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, weights['weights_conv2'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv_2d_2_plus_bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_2d_2, biases['bc2'])
        conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv_2d_2_plus_bias, name=scope)

    tf.summary.histogram('conv2_output_distribution', conv2)
    tf.summary.histogram('con2_before_relu', conv_2d_2_plus_bias)

    # norm2
    with tf.name_scope('norm2'):
        norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(conv2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                          name='norm2')
    tf.summary.histogram('norm2_output_distribution', norm2)

    # pool2
    with tf.name_scope('pool2'):
        pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(norm2,
                               ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='VALID',
                               name='pool2')
    tf.summary.histogram('pool2_output_distribution', pool2)

    # conv3
    with tf.name_scope('conv3') as scope:
        conv_2d_3 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool2, weights['weights_conv3'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv_2d_3_plus_bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_2d_3, biases['bc3'])
        conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv_2d_3_plus_bias, name=scope)

    tf.summary.histogram('con3_output_distribution', conv3)
    tf.summary.histogram('con3_before_relu', conv_2d_3_plus_bias)

    # conv4
    with tf.name_scope('conv4') as scope:
        conv_2d_4 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv3, weights['weights_conv4'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv_2d_4_plus_bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_2d_4, biases['bc4'])
        conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv_2d_4_plus_bias, name=scope)

    tf.summary.histogram('con4_output_distribution', conv4)
    tf.summary.histogram('con4_before_relu', conv_2d_4_plus_bias)

    # conv5
    with tf.name_scope('conv5') as scope:
        conv_2d_5 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv4, weights['weights_conv5'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv_2d_5_plus_bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_2d_5, biases['bc5'])
        conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv_2d_5_plus_bias, name=scope)

    tf.summary.histogram('con5_output_distribution', conv5)
    tf.summary.histogram('con5_before_relu', conv_2d_5_plus_bias)

    # pool3
    pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv5,
                           ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                           strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                           padding='VALID',
                           name='pool5')
    tf.summary.histogram('pool3_output_distribution', pool3)

    # local1
    with tf.variable_scope('local1') as scope:
        # Move everything into depth so we can perform a single matrix multiply.
        shape_d = pool3.get_shape()
        shape = shape_d[1] * shape_d[2] * shape_d[3]
        # tf_shape = tf.stack(shape)
        tf_shape = 1024

        print("shape:", shape, shape_d[1], shape_d[2], shape_d[3])

        reshape = tf.reshape(pool3, [-1, tf_shape])
        weight_local1 = \
            tf.get_variable(name='weight_local1', shape=[tf_shape, 2046], dtype=tf.float32,
                            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(uniform=False, dtype=tf.float32))
        bias_local1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [2046]), trainable=True, name='bias_local1')
        local1_before_relu = tf.matmul(reshape, weight_local1) + bias_local1
        local1 = tf.nn.relu(local1_before_relu, name=scope.name)

    tf.summary.histogram('local1_output_distribution', local1)
    tf.summary.histogram('local1_before_relu', local1_before_relu)

    tf.summary.histogram('local1_weights', weight_local1)
    tf.summary.histogram('local1_biases', bias_local1)

    # local2
    with tf.variable_scope('local2') as scope:
        # Move everything into depth so we can perform a single matrix multiply.
        weight_local2 = \
            tf.get_variable(name='weight_local2', shape=[2046, 2046], dtype=tf.float32,
                            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(uniform=False, dtype=tf.float32))
        bias_local2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [2046]), trainable=True, name='bias_local2')
        local2_before_relu = tf.matmul(local1, weight_local2) + bias_local2
        local2 = tf.nn.relu(local2_before_relu, name=scope.name)

    tf.summary.histogram('local2_output_distribution', local2)
    tf.summary.histogram('local2_before_relu', local2_before_relu)

    tf.summary.histogram('local2_weights', weight_local2)
    tf.summary.histogram('local2_biases', bias_local2)

    # linear Wx + b
    with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
        weight_softmax = \
            tf.Variable(
                tf.truncated_normal([2046, n_classes], stddev=1 / 1024, dtype=tf.float32), name='weight_softmax')
        bias_softmax = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, tf.float32, [n_classes]), trainable=True, name='bias_softmax')
        softmax_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(local2, weight_softmax), bias_softmax, name=scope.name)

    tf.summary.histogram('softmax_output_distribution', softmax_linear)
    tf.summary.histogram('softmax_weights', weight_softmax)
    tf.summary.histogram('softmax_biases', bias_softmax)

    tf.summary.histogram('weights_conv1', weights['weights_conv1'])
    tf.summary.histogram('weights_conv2', weights['weights_conv2'])
    tf.summary.histogram('weights_conv3', weights['weights_conv3'])
    tf.summary.histogram('weights_conv4', weights['weights_conv4'])
    tf.summary.histogram('weights_conv5', weights['weights_conv5'])

    tf.summary.histogram('biases_conv1', biases['bc1'])
    tf.summary.histogram('biases_conv2', biases['bc2'])
    tf.summary.histogram('biases_conv3', biases['bc3'])
    tf.summary.histogram('biases_conv4', biases['bc4'])
    tf.summary.histogram('biases_conv5', biases['bc5'])

    return softmax_linear

# Note that this is the RMSE
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    # Note that the dimension of cost is [batch_size, 1]. Every example has one output and a batch
    # is a number of examples.
    cost = tf.sqrt(tf.square(tf.subtract(predictions, y_valence)))
    cost_scalar = tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(cost, confidence_holder), reduction_indices=0)
    # Till here cost_scolar will have the following shape: [[#num]]... That is why I used cost_scalar[0]
    tf.summary.scalar("loss", cost_scalar[0])

with tf.name_scope('train'):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_scalar)
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe the weights are not changing since most of the activation is around 0. NOT SURE.

Comment: Are you sure that the weights are used in the graph?  If yes, could you please attach the code (or a simplified version of it)?

Comment: I guess that the shapes for the weights are correct since after running the mnist with summary code, the weights' graph in tensorboard achieve similar shapes (didn't appear to vary a lot), while at the same time, the graph shows a drop in the loss and raise in the accuracy.

Comment: @I.Ayoub I am having a similar issue in my convolutional network. did you troubleshoot this? Your learning rate seems fine and small enough, but why weight histogram remains constant? Could it be that the number of epochs are not large enough?

Comment: @mamafoku, Well I have released that this behavior is always the case. And it is true as well. And when you train your model on the MNIST data set you will get almost the same shape for the histogram/distribution of the weights. I didn't post an answer since I don't have enough answer for this issue.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Any update on this?

Comment: **First, as a potential quick fix:** try reducing the value to which you initialize your biases (make them 0.01, instead of 0.1). If the magnitude of the biases dwarf the magnitude of the weights network optimisation will make changes to the biases instead of the weights, and you can push yourself into sigmoid saturation and thus stagnate training.

Comment: Otherwise could you provide some information on the nature of `frames`. I assume this is your data, but can't run the network without knowing what this data looks like. Also, you should be using a `tf.placeholder` to feed data into the network for training. I cannot see one of these.

Comment: @FinleyGibson, I found this behaviour will almost all neural networks. Can you provide us a reference for cases that show how weights are getting modified? (I mean their distribution)

Answer (score 3):

from https://jhui.github.io/2017/03/12/TensorBoard-visualize-your-learning/

I think the distribution is just another way to represent histogram with step.

I guess most red line in mid mean the max in histgram and each four line mean percent divide to 0 25% 50% 75% per side